# Proving an upper bound for some quantity

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Is it possible to prove this inequality: 
$$(x+v-1)^{x-1} / {(x-1)!} \le x^v, \forall \ (x,v) \in \mathbb{N^2}$$

I tried to find a counterexample, but I couldn't and I have no clue of where to start for proving it.

Comment: I think $x=3$ and $v=1$ is a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality is not true. Setting $v=1$, we have
$$\frac{x^x}{(x-1)!} \leq x \iff x^{x-1} \leq (x-1)!$$
Which is definitely not true. This inequality does not hold the other way either, since for $u=v=2$, we have
$$(2+2-1)^1 \le 2^2 \iff 3 \le 4$$

Comment: As in the comment from Akos Somogyi,  $3^{3-1}=9>2=(3-1)!$